# Integrate Azure Active Directory B2C with Angular app

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We currently hosted an angular app in azure and are using ADAL for authentication.

Now, we want it to be used by external customers as well and hence wish to integrate Azure AD B2C with our app.

First, to test it locally, I created Azure AD B2C tenant and registered both my Angular app and ASP.NET core Web API with that tenant. The app runs on http://localhost:4200/ and Web API runs on http://localhost:53040.

I could not figure out how to replace the ADAL code with the MSAL code in the my angular app.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Im facing today exact same scenario and Im trying this "official" sample:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular/samples/MSALAngularDemoApp

I hope it helps anybody else, that's the only good Angular 4+ sample I was able to find.

Comment: I got this working with Angular 7 but you need the rx/js compat library added

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to adapt this sample for an Angular 7 app hosted on an Azure storage static website invoking an B2C-protected Function App API. So far I'm encountering [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56411863/852956).