# Angular app which invokes B2C-secured Function App API receives 500, Function receives 404

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

### *Angular* site hosted on an *Azure storage account* as a *static website* receives 500 when it's invoking an Azure B2C-protected *Function App* function. The function is receiving a 404.

---

### Update

The original title for this question was "Angular app which invokes B2C-secured Functions App receives `401 Unauthorized` response". The solution was, as @Alex AIT suggested (below), to replace the `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>` in the Function App's *Issuer URL* with **`https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/`**. I.e., remove the trailing *`.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`* segments. In a subsequent chat session, Alex pointed out that the policy is part of the path such as `https://<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.c‌​om/<policyname>/v2.0` or `https://<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/<tenantguid>/<policyname>/v2.0`. However either of those paths for the Function App's *Issuer URL* reverts to the 401 response.

After resolving the 401 issue, the Angular SPA app now receives 500. However, the invoked API function is receiving a 404. The Function App's log stream indicates `Failed to download OpenID configuration from 'https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration': The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` So the policy is not getting attached.

---

My objective is to establish a secure, serverless Angular web application which is statically-hosted on an Azure Storage website (i.e., within the storage account's `$web` container). There are two projects: a *public* `SPA` *Angular 7+* project and a *protected* `API` *Function App* project. Because Azure storage account static websites only allow public anonymous access to all files, the *Angular* app-hosting blob container's files (the website's files) are not secured. But the *Angular* app's invocations of the *Azure Functions* API calls are secured. The *Function App* `API` project is protected via Azure AD B2C authentication.

Toward this end, I have attempted to adapt the technique outlined in [Single-Page Application built on MSAL.js with Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/) and [Node.js Web API with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi). I was able to get these samples to run. And furthermore I was able to modify their settings to authenticate against my own Azure B2C tenant (rather than against Microsoft's B2C tenant) and run them locally. But I didn't attempt to deploy these sample projects to Azure and figure out the required tweaks for the settings. I skipped the deployment exercise because I'm not a Node.js developer.

But my subsequent adaptation of the code in those (Node.js) sample projects to my statically-hosted Angular SPA project and to my Azure Functions API project is yielding `401 Unauthorized` whenever the API is invoked from the SPA. So I would like to understand how to resolve this issue.

### The setup

#### Assumptions/Prerequisites

1. An Azure *B2C Tenant* has been created
2. *Identity providers* have been configured for the *B2C Tenant*
3. A `Sign-up and Sign-in` *user flow* policy has been configured for the *B2C Tenant*

   - Make a note of its name. We'll refer to it's name below as `<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`
4. An Azure Storage account has been created with its *Static website* feature enabled
5. An *Angular* app has been created

   1. The `@azure/msal-angular` package has been installed
   2. In `app-routing.module.ts`,

      - the `useHash` option has been set: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],`

        - Hash-routing is necessary to accommodate static hosting
      - A secure component has been created and a protected-route established

      ```
             const routes: Routes = [
                 { path: 'secure', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
                 { path: 'state', redirectTo: 'secure' }, // HACK/TODO
                 { path: 'error', redirectTo: 'secure' }, // HACK/TODO
                 { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
             ];
      ```
6. An Azure *Function App* has been created

   - Make a note of the *Function App*'s URL
7. The following function has been created in the *Function App* for testing purposes. And it's been published to Azure:

   ```cs
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
   using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
   using Newtonsoft.Json;

   namespace SomeCompany.Functions
   {
       public static class HttpTriggerCSharp
       {
           [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
           public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
               [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
               ILogger log)
           {
               log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

               string name = req.Query["name"];

               string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
               dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
               name = name ?? data?.name;

               return name != null
                   ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                   : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

#### B2C Tenant

API Application

1. Create the `API` Application (i.e., name it *“**API**”)*
2. Make a note of its *Application ID*

   - The *Application ID* will be used later in the Function App's AAD Auth settings
3. Set *Include Web App / Web API* to ***Yes***
4. Set the *Allow implicit flow* to ***Yes***
5. Set the *Reply URL* to ***`https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`***

   - Suffix the *Function App*'s URL with `/.auth/login/aad/callback`
6. Set the *App ID URI* segment to ***“API”***

   - Yields: `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/API`

SPA Application

1. Create the `SPA` Application (i.e., name it *“**SPA**”)*
2. Set *Include Web App / Web API* to ***Yes***
3. Set *Allow implicit flow* to ***Yes***
4. Set the *Reply URL* to ***http://localhost:4200***
5. In the *API access* tab, add the `API` application API

   - The only available scope *“Access this app on behalf of the signed-in user (user_impersonation)”* will be pre-selected

#### Primary (Non-B2C) Tenant

Function App

1. In the *Authentication / Authorization* blade,

   - Set *App Service Authentication* to ***On***
   - Set *Action to take when request is not authenticated* to ***Log in with Azure Active Directory***
   - In the *Authentication Providers* section, configure the *Azure Active Directory* provider as follows:

     - Set *Management Mode* to ***Advanced***
     - Set *Client ID* to the B2C `API` application's *Application ID*
     - Set the *Issuer Url* to ***`https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`***
2. Save these *Authentication / Authorization* settings

Azure Application

1. In the *Angular* application's `app.module.ts` `NgModule` **import** property, set:

   ```js
   MsalModule.forRoot({
       clientID: '<B2C Tenant |> SPA Application |> Application ID>',

       // Note, for authority, the following doesn't work:
       //    B2C Tenant |> User flows (policies) |> <SignUpAndSignInPolicyName> |> Run user flow |> URL at top of the `Run user flow` blade
       //    I.e., `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`
       // Supposedly (according to various blog posts), that URL should be used as the `authority`. So, why doesn't it work?.
       // The following URL works. However, the B2C portal indicates that `login.microsoftonline.com` is to be deprecated soon
       authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>',

       // B2C Tenant |> Applications |> API |> Published Scopes |> `user_impersonation` | FULL SCOPE VALUE
       consentScopes: ['https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/API/user_impersonation'],
   })
   ```
2. Create a component named `Secure`

   - `ng g c Secure -s --skipTests`
   - secure.component.ts

     ```js
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
     import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

     @Component({
         selector: 'app-secure',
         templateUrl: './secure.component.html',
     })
     export class SecureComponent  {

         constructor(private http: HttpClient, private msalService: MsalService) { }

         azureTestFunctionResponse: string;

         callApiWithAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
             const url = 'https://<function_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp?name=HelloFromAzureFunction';
             const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` });
             const subscription: Subscription = this.http.get(url, { headers: httpHeaders , responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(_ => {
                 this.azureTestFunctionResponse = _;
                 subscription.unsubscribe();
             });
         }

         invokeB2cSecuredAzureFunction() {
             // B2C Tenant |> `API` Application |> Published Scopes |> `user_impersonation` scope |> Full Scope Value
             const tokenRequest: string[] = ['https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/API/user_impersonation'];
             this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
                 .then(tokenResponse => {
                     this.callApiWithAccessToken(tokenResponse);
                 })
                 .catch(error1 => {
                     this.msalService.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                         .then(tokenResponse => {
                             this.callApiWithAccessToken(tokenResponse);
                         })
                         .catch(error => {
                             console.log('Error acquiring the access token to call the Web api:\n' + error);
                         });
                 });
         }

     }
     ```
   - secure.component.html

     ```html
     <h4>Secure Component</h4>

     <button (click)="invokeB2cSecuredAzureFunction()">Fetch data from B2C-secured Azure functions</button>
     <hr />
     <div>{{azureTestFunctionResponse}}</div>
     ```
3. app.component.html

   ```html
   <div style="text-align:center">
       <h4> {{ title }} </h4>
   </div>
   <mat-card style="float: left;">
       This site is a configuration demonstration of a secure, serverless Angular web application. The site is statically hosted on an
       <em>Azure Storage</em> website (<code>$web</code> container). The site's backend is secured
       by Azure <em>Business-to-Consumer</em>&nbsp;<span class="acronym">(B2C)</span> authentication. The site interacts with a secure
       <em>Azure Functions</em>&nbsp;<span class="acronym">API</span>.
   </mat-card>

   <p style="text-align: center;"><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a routerLink="/secure" routerLinkActive="active">Secure</a></p>

   <p style="text-align: center;"><router-outlet></router-outlet></p>
   ```
4. Serve the app locally: `ng serve`
5. Click on the *Secure* link

   - Which navigates to the `/secure` route
   - Which prompts the user to authenticate
6. Click on the `Fetch data from B2C-secured Azure function` button
7. Server returns a `401 Not Authorized` response
8. If the SPA app's `Reply URL` is updated to the `SPA` static website URL and the SPA files are published, the `401` likewise gets returned when the API function is called.

So I'm not sure what's configured wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issuer of your tenant:

```
https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>
```

But if you open this URL in your browser, it will show your the issuer you search for.

It should be something like this:

```
https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_guid>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/SignUpAndSignInPolicyName/v2.0
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
```

It might also be a good idea to choose either b2clogin.com and login.microsoftonline.com for both the Azure Function and the Angular app. I don't think you can mix them like this.

If you still have issues, you could try this as a scope instead of `/user_impersonation`:

```
https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/API/.default
```

Or try adding `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/API/user_impersonation` to the allowed audiences in the Azure Function.

Comment: Switching to `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_guid>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0` got past the `401`s. But now the API call is returning `500`s. I couldn't get the `.../API/.default` scope to work. None of the suggested `b2clogin` URLs work for the `MsalModule.forRoot({ authority ...})`.

Comment: Error 500 schould no longer be a b2c/auth issue - I would suggest checking your function logs

Comment: The functions log stream is indicating `Failed to download OpenID configuration from 'https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_guid>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration': The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

Comment: This is because it is missing the policy. `https://<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyname>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` should work, at least it works in the browser

Comment: Interesting. Initially, I incorrectly included `.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>` in the *Primary (Non-B2C) Tenant | Function App | App Service Authentication | Azure Active Directory provider | Issuer Url* which had resulted in the 401s. Removing it resolved 401s. But now it's unclear where to specify the `<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`.

Comment: the policy is part of the path, see my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue as you described an looking though the responses posted I was able to solve it by changing the authority to:

> `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`

The standard one (`https://<b2c_tenant_name>.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>`) was causing me to get a 401 when I tried to use the token on my Function app

**Edit : Adding code sample**

While my code is using react environment variables it's all just JS and should work the same in an angular app.

```
import * as Msal from 'msal';

/** @type {import('msal').Configuration} */
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        authority: 'https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>',
        validateAuthority: false,
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
};
/** @type {import('msal').AuthenticationParameters} */
const reqParams = {
    scopes: [process.env.REACT_APP_SCOPE],
};
const clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
clientApplication.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        if (error.message.indexOf('AADB2C90118') >= 0) {
            //User clicked forgot password
            clientApplication.authority = 'https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<ResetPasswordPolicyName>';
            clientApplication.loginRedirect(reqParams);
            return;
        }
        return console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: When I try that value for the `MsalModule.forRoot.authority` field, the metatadata URL that MSAL-js attempts to fetch is malformed: `https://<b2c_tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<b2c_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<SignUpAndSignInPolicyName>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` which redundantly suffixes the `/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` path.

Comment: It's possible the angular code is adding that, i'm using the MSAL package directly (https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal). I did have to set `validateAuthority` to false, will try edit my answer to include the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to change the security for the azure function in the standard settings to Anonymous (from Function) ... It seems it was expecting also a function code in addition to the bearer token... Took me 5+ hours to find out, as all my focus was on what could be wrong with the JWT access token, or the AADB2C configs etc ...

Oops, maybe I posted this in the wrong thread, I was getting 401 actually ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with the web api (https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello). The sample is calling this protected resource, but the sample has [hard coded the domain](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/blob/master/index.js#L19) `login.microsoftonline.com`, which then causes issues with the passport library (middleware), which extracts and validates the access_token, propagates the claims in the access_token to the verify callback and lets the framework finish the remaining authentication process.

Because the web api is using a different authority, the passport library is unable to validate the token because the format of the authority url between `login.microsoftonline.com` and `{tenantName}.b2clogin.com` are different. For example, when using `{tenantName}.b2clogin.com`, the policy has to be included, but when previously using `login.microsoftonline.com`, it was not necessary to include the policy in the url for passport to validate the token.

We will update the web api and all the impacted samples as soon as possible. You can try out the api call by [targeting this branch](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/compare/jennyf/b2clogin), which runs on localhost:5000. In the code, update the api endpoint to hit `ApiEndpoint = "http://localhost:5000/hello"`. Will update here when the samples have been fixed.